# Android: How to initialize a variable of type "Location" (other than making it equal to null)

Tags: android, geolocation

I'm looking to test some code I've written and to do so I need to construct a variable of type Location and to give it a long / lat value but I'm unsure how I would do so. Any ideas?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

[The API documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html) is quite clear on this. First create a new Location instance:

```
Location loc = new Location("dummyprovider");
```

And then use the setter methods to set the location parameters you need, e.g.:

```
loc.setLatitude(20.3);
loc.setLongitude(52.6);
```

Comment: Location loc = new Location("");

Comment: @AdamJohns: The provider is supposed to specify what exactly acquired the specific coordinate fix. In the `Location` object it's just a string field and can be anything. When dealing with actual location fixes it'll often be equal to one of the constants in `LocationManager` such as [`GPS_PROVIDER`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#GPS_PROVIDER) which equals `"gps"`, which would mean that the specific location was acquired via GPS.

Answer (score 7):

```
Location object = new Location("service Provider");
```

it will create an object of Type Location that contains the initial Latitude and Longitude at location '0' to get the initial values use

```
double lat = object.getLatitude();
double lng = object.getLongitude();
```

Answer (score 6):

In Kotlin using `LocationManager` class you can pass the required location provider like:

```
val location = Location(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER) // OR GPS_PROVIDER based on the requirement
location.latitude = 42.125
location.longitude = 55.123
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write a method:

```
Location createNewLocation(double longitude, double latitude) {
    Location location = new Location("dummyprovider");
    location.setLongitude(longitude);
    location.setLatitude(latitude);
    return location;
}
```

And then call it:

```
Location myLoc = createNewLocation(dLong, dLati);
```

Or you can use string with Double.parse():

```
Location myLoc = createNewLocation(Double.parse("s.Long"), Double.parse("s.Lati"));
```